# Qt/C++ - Closing two widgets when one is closed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a main window which creates two widgets: the "main window" with menus and the main application and a widget that makes available various settings in its own window, disconnected from the main application.

Is there an event in Qt such that I can force the settings widget to close if i close/hide/X out the main application's window?

Comment: Why not make the widget with settings a child of the main window?

Comment: What do you want that : [close event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) can't do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1- make the settings widget a child of the main window

2- use an event filter to detect the close event of the main window (see `QObject::installEventFilter()` and `QCloseEvent`)

3- Override `closeEvent` int the main window

Comment: I added `mywidget->close()` to `MainWindow::closeEvent()`. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The main window has a closeEvent function you can override to close the other window:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    otherWindow->close();
    QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This is what I did. thanks for the code, I would have forgotten to call `QMainWindow::closeEvent()`