# Making two QT dialogs close each others

Tags: c++, qt

I've seen this question : [Qt/C++ - Closing two widgets when one is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781409/qt-c-closing-two-widgets-when-one-is-closed)
However I do not have this MainWindow <-> Widget relationship.

```
class Ui_DialogResults
{
public:
    QDialog *_Dialog;
    void setupUi(QDialog *Dialog)
    {
_Dialog = Dialog;
    }
};
class Ui_DialogSearch
{
public:
    QDialog *_Dialog;
    void setupUi(QDialog *Dialog)
    {
_Dialog = Dialog;
    }
};
namespace Ui {
    class Ui_Search : public Ui_DialogSearch {};
    class Ui_Results : public Ui_DialogResults {};
}
class Search : public QDialog{
public:
Search(){
ui.setup(this);
}
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        //saves scan settings here
        pResults->_Dialog->close();
    }
Ui::Ui_Search ui;
Ui::Ui_Results *pResults;
}
class Results : public QDialog{
public:
Results(){
ui.setup(this);
}
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        //saves scan settings here
        pSearch->_Dialog->close();
    }
Ui::Ui_Search *pSearch;
Ui::Ui_Results ui;
}
```

When a Search dialog is open, a result dialog is also open and vice versa.
The Thread opening both dialogs also fills the pointer in the Search instance towards Result and vice versa.
Each class has overriden `closeEvent()`so that they close each others as such.
I would have expected cross recursive consequences and crash but it apparently works perfectly.
Qt doc states

```
The QCloseEvent class contains parameters that describe a close event.

Close events are sent to widgets that the user wants to close, usually by choosing "Close" from the window menu, or by clicking the X title bar button. They are also sent when you call QWidget::close() to close a widget programmatically.
```

Is this UB?

Comment: What does "UB" mean?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a mutual reference between the search and results dialog, you can easily avoid any potential incidents by setting pointers to null and doing some basic checks.

The dialog that initiates the closing sets its own pointer in the other dialog to null, copies the pointer to the other to a temporary value, sets the other pointer to null and closes the other dialog through the temp pointer. If the pointer to the other dialog is already null, that would mean the other dialog has initiated the closing, so do nothing except call the base class implementation in order to close the dialog.

Comment: Why copy pointer to temp, null original, and close dialog with temp pointer ? Why not just close dialog and null pointer afterwards ?

Comment: That might be redundant, but just as another insurance that nothing will go wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Is it undefined Behavior? No. Undocumented? Possibly. (Did not find any explicit statement that this is supposed to work). Unintended? Probably not. Qt is pretty mature, although not always documented to the last detail. I bet they only allow only one close event per widget.